# Vue JS: how to async load and render components when they are visible in the viewport

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, axios, vue-component, viewport

I am relatively new to Vue JS, and I am working on a website that publishes articles that contain different types of content (videos, images) and polls (multiple poll forms on the same page). The site is running on CraftCMS & MySQL, so the content of the templates is parsed server sided.

I created a poll component so I could reuse it on the same page. Works fine, but then all data in the template is loaded on initial page load, which I would like to prevent due to large queries.

The solution (which I was also using before I started rebuilding this site with Vue JS), is to load these parts async when they're in the viewport. With a combination of a viewport detection library and jQuery I simply loaded the Craft template (/includes/poll). But now it's built with Vue, I am a little bit confused on how to manage this.

After hours of searching, I got the async part working, using a async component, but this will still load and render all components after the page is loaded, even when they're not visible for the user.

So far, this is what I got:

```
CraftCMS template (/includes/poll)
Note: tags will be parsed server sided by Craft, not Vue 

<poll inline-template>

    <div id="poll-component-{{ id }}" >
                
        {% if userHasVoted %}
        
            show results of poll
            
        {% else }
        
            show poll form that will fire vote()
        
        {% endif %}
        
    </div>
</poll>
```

Async component

```
Vue.component('poll', function(e) {

    return {
        
        component: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                                    
            // Request
            axios.get('/includes/poll', {
                params: {
                    id: 123, // NEED TO GET THIS FROM HTML ATTRIBUTE 
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                                
                resolve({
                    template: response.data,
                    created() {
                    },
                    mounted () {  
                    },                  
                    props: {
                        id: String,
                        title: String,
                    },  
                    data () {
                        return {
                            hasVoted: false,
                            isVoting: false
                        }
                    },
                    methods: {
                        vote: function() {
                            // API call to server, send vote, on success reload the poll template again (includes/poll) 
                        }
                    }                           
                })
                
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        }),
        loading: Vue.component('loader', {
            template: '<p>loading...</p>'
        }),
        error: Vue.component('load-error', {
            template: '<p>error loading component</p>'
        }),
        delay: 200,
        timeout: 10000
    }       
});
```

And in my Craft templates I add the html element:

```
<poll id="123"></poll>
```

I got 2 problems:

1. I can't pass the id to the axios/http/get call, which is required show the right poll data
2. The component is always loaded even when it's not in the viewport

Hope anybody can advise me on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Arjan! how did you solve this problem?